# space-time clustering :: point patterns in different spaces

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, geospatial, spatstat

By following [these instructions from Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12938629/creating-and-cropping-grid-in-r-cran) I have created a ppp object using the **spatstat** package in R.

Because my data set includes a time dimension, I want to expand this analysis to consider the 3D space-time for clustering analysis.

[The SPATSTAT VERSION 2 Preliminary Announcement 6th revision](http://www.spatstat.org/spatstat/spatstat2.html), dated 9th February 2010, suggests this should be possible with the new R package **spatstat2**.  The announcement says:

> The new class pp of point patterns will support:
>
> - multiple marks attached to each point 
>     (e.g. trees can be marked by their species, diameter at breast height and leaf toxicity assay).
> - point patterns in different spaces, 
>   including 3D points, 2D space-time, 3D space-time, 1D networks in 2D space, different distance metrics
> - marks of ANY type 
>     (each mark can be a window, a point pattern, a function etc etc)

However, beyond the announcement, I cannot find many additional details about the anticipated **spatstat2** package.  And I also cannot install the package from CRAN:

```
package ‘spatstat2’ is not available (for R version 3.0.3)
```

My questions are:

1. what are the best methods available in R for clustering analysis of events data (each event with geospatial coordinates X, Y, plus a Timestamp) ?
2. what has come to pass with the **spatstat2** package ?  Is it available ?

Thank you for your help!

Keith Helfrich

Answer (score 1):

Regarding point 1:
I'm no expert on this, but I think the package stpp on CRAN could be useful.

Regarding point 2:
spatstat2 is definitely not available yet, and realistically it will not come out this year (personal correspondence with the authors).

Comment: Hi Ege, thanks for your input!  I've explored the 'stpp' package, but could not find the ability to perform spatio-temporal clustering.  Re: the desire to do so with 'spatstat', I've sent an inquiry off to the R-Sig-Geo mailing list but did not receive any reply.  Still searching for an answer to how to accomplish it.

Comment: Hi Keith: I have a space-time data that I need to cluster (X,Y,time) . Let me know how you solved this problem. Thanks!